# What is the best way to search log in AWS cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm running AWS lambda. And I should find some informations from the Cloudwatch logs.

And What am I doing seems to too inefficient. But I don't know how to work.
I want to know more efficient way.

What am I doing is...

1. I have some ids

```
1111-1111-111
2222-2222-222
3333-3333-333
...
```

2. Search for specific messages with id in AWS log insight conolse

```
fields @timestamp, @logStream ,@message
| filter @message like /myId/
| sort @timestamp desc
| parse @message '"myId" : "*"' as my_id
| filter my_id like /1111-1111-111/
```

3. Download result csv file.
4. Parse @logStream with python

```py
 with open('1111-1111-111.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     for row in reader:
         print(str(i) +": " +row['@logStream'])
```

5. get logStreams and search again in logInsight console

```
2021/06/05/[$LATEST]1111111111111
2021/06/05/[$LATEST]1111111111111
2021/06/05/[$LATEST]1111111111111
2021/06/05/[$LATEST]2222222222222
2021/06/05/[$LATEST]3333333333333
2021/06/05/[$LATEST]3333333333333
2021/06/05/[$LATEST]3333333333333
2021/06/05/[$LATEST]3333333333333
2021/06/05/[$LATEST]4444444444444
...
```

6. Search again with logStreams and get what I really want.

```
fields @timestamp, @logStream ,@message
| filter @logStream='2021/06/05/[$LATEST]1111111111111'
| filter @message like /file_name/
| parse @message "'file_name': '*'" as file_name
```

7. After getting file_name, I should search again inside file with `myId`. Because I'm not sure because of same logStreams.

If I do this manually, This is too hard. And If I do this with aws boto3 it's also hard for me because I'm not familiar with boto3 logs client wait process and result. Also I think there would be better way.
Could you suggest to me better workflow?

Comment: What is it you're actually after?

Comment: After getting file names, I want to download the files which are JSON from AWS S3. 
And after answering your question, I'm wondering if there is a way to search inside s3 JSON files.